# Trying to connect using ssh2_auth_pubkey_file()

Tags: ssh, php

I am trying to make a php script that runs on the terminal that would connect to a remote server by ssh and retrieve a file. this is my code so far

```
#!/usr/bin/php -q
<?php
$cwd = dirname(__FILE__).'/';
$filename = 'retrive-this.file';
$host = 'hostip';

$connection = ssh2_connect($host, 22, array('hostkey'=>'ssh-rsa'));
$methods = ssh2_auth_pubkey_file($connection, 'remoteuser',
                                 $cwd.'ssh/id_rsa.pub',
                                 $cwd.'ssh/id_rsa', "it's an inception");
var_dump($methods);

//ssh2_scp_recv($connection, "/remote/server/path/to/$filename", $cwd.$filename);
?>
```

for now I am having problems with the `ssh2_auth_pubkey_file()` function, when I run the script it returns this:

```
PHP Warning:  ssh2_auth_pubkey_file(): Authentication failed for remoteuser using public key in /home/tonyl/Projects/get-file-ssh.php on line 10
bool(false)
```

The key files have permission `-rw-r--r--` (644). Also the public key is already added to the remoteuser's authorized keys. I am able to ssh using the ssh command as normal, so I don't think it is a ssh authorization problem, but who knows. I am new to ssh and the ssh2 php library.

I can connect using `ssh2_auth_password()` if I enable it in the remote sshd_config file, but I don't want to do that since it decreases security tranfer.

Any ideas of what I can do.

Comment: Default dir would be `.ssh`, not `ssh`, might that be the problem? And id_rsa should really be 0600, owned by the user which connects.

Comment: If this works with ssh from the command line, This is nearly impossible to debug without stepping into libssh2 with a debugger. You could also try first to run PHP with strace to see if you can find something fishy.

Comment: I can at least confirm this is the _exact_ error message one gets when the public/private key files don't exist.

Comment: Well, all errors actually, so indeed, you're right about it being very difficult to debug.

Comment: @Wrikken the ssh folder is in my script folder, I copied the key files there so that it can have access. If it was a apache webpage I would guess the users running it would be www-data, but since it is a command line script I am guessing the users is me then? if that's the case I have access. I changed it to 0600 permits and still the same outcome.


@Artefacto I was a bit afraid it might come to that. I am going to see if I can get more info by tracing


@Wrikken I thought this might be the problem, but I echo the content of the files in the script and it can read them.

Comment: If the script is running from web page the process is probably running as `apache:apache` unless your sysadmin changed it in your conf file.  If you do make a change to your conf file you'll need to restart apache.  Good luck.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is a known bug in php: password protected private key cannot be used on certain combinaisons.

See: https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=58573

> ssh2_auth_pubkey_file() is broken when the public key file is protected with a  password AND libssh2 is compiled with libgcrypt, which is what debian/ubuntu and probably others do. I'm working on a solution for this bug, but if you need this working rebuild libssh2 yourself with OpenSSL.

A workaround may be to store the private key unencrypted.
To decrypt the key:

```
openssl rsa -in id_rsa -out id_rsaNOPASSWORD
```

and then use the file id_rsaNOPASSWORD without supplying the fifth parameter 'passphrase'.
It works, but you'll have to be careful with your decrypted key file. Anyway, the level of security is not really terribly affected, because even with an encrypted key, you would still need to pass the passphrase unencrypted to the ssh2_auth_pubkey_file function ...

Hope it helps.

Comment: You could just use http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/ . Not only does it not have this issue - it supports more key formats than PHP's SSH extension - PuTTY, PKCS8, PKCS1, XML, passwords, no passwords, etc.

Answer (score 0):

this looks like the error right here.  **FILE** is a filepath isn't it?  so it looks something like /somedir/somefile.php and all you have done is add a / on the end of .php so I don't think this is really valid.  see http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php

```
$cwd = dirname(__FILE__).'/';
```

also, other people have been having problems with ssh2_auth_pubkey_file
returning false under all conditions.  you may want to submit a bug report.  I was hoping to use this function.  I don't know how to use it because I have no idea how to supply a private key.

I think the code you want is

```
if (!defined('__DIR__')) {
    $iPos = strrpos(__FILE__, "/");
    define("__DIR__", substr(__FILE__, 0, $iPos) . "/");
}
$cwd=__DIR__ . '/';
```

and keep in mind that when it comes to the remote directory, you should be using ssh2_sftp_realpath().

dirname() has been reported to be unreliable.

Comment: The code `$cwd = dirname(__FILE__).'/';` does return the right directory: `/home/tonyl/Projects/` I don't think that is the problem and neither `dirname()` since I am using it for local folder, not for the remote folder.
Thanks for the help though, I think I am going to see if there is a bug report about the C library or PHP's

Comment: In doubt just use your path like this -> /home/user/dir/ 'cause the problem is not your path it is the ssh2_auth_pubkey_file php function. I'm stacked here with the same f**** problem

Comment: Did you guys manage to find a solution? I'm stuck with the same problem here. Is you key using a `secret`? If so, one likely candidate that's causing this is bug https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=58573

Answer (score 0):

I have been using this function for around 3 years and for some reason a new server that I was configuring didn´t work. I was about to jump by the balcony when I found this :

```
ssh-keygen -m PEM -t rsa -b 4096
```

using the link @megar answered years ago.

Hope it helps someone else, this was hard!